# (TS) Unused Label error when trying to get child component access using ViewChild

Tags: angular

Im facing a trouble when trying to get access of a child component in parent component. I imported the components and tried to declare ViewChild method on the nginit. But when I specify the variable name it says unused label. Sorry Im a very beginner with Angular

Here is the code snippet in which you can see the error. I need that **userListComponent** in another function to reinitialise that component by calling its function. But because of this error I dont have access into that component.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the

```
@ViewChild(UserListComponent) userListComponent: UserListComponent
```

outside of `ngOnInit` function. Your `userListComponent` will be initialized in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle event.

```
export class TemplateCategoryNewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild(UserListComponent) userListComponent: UserListComponent

   ngOnInit() { ... }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      // here `userListComponent` is available
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation for the @ViewChild directive](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). Such directive is used in the body of the class, when you define the userListComponent field, not inside the ngOnInit method. So just move

```
@ViewChild(UserListComponent) userListComponent: UserListComponent
```

outside ngOnInit.